# Why wont my computer boot Ubuntu from my flash drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-8, live-usb

I have a windows 8 Gateway desktop PC and I was wanting to install Ubuntu (13.10) on it.

Firstly I created a bootable USB using [PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/), the process was successful, and when I plug the flashdrive in using windows 7 AND 8, it is no longer recognized as TOSHIBA 8GB, but Install Ubuntu (H:), whenever I go into the BIOS of the Gateway PC, I set my removable disk as the first boot priority, and disable secure boot, and Launch CSM was set to always, and even after all these setting changes I still boot into windows 8.

I did notice that the motherboard in the Gateway PC was an exclusive motherboard, I don't know if that means anything but it is very frustrating and I would like some help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Gage

Comment: Are you using 64bit version of Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in Windows 8 because of the UEFI system. Boot into win8 and browse to the CD. Start the wubi installer and do as it says. It will then install Ubuntu. Cheers!
**Note:** Use the wubi installer only if you have upgraded from an older windows system.

Comment: thought it would work nice cuz i installed 13.10 alongside win8 on my friend's pc and it worked perfectly

Comment: Yeah his pc was upgraded from XP to 8. Thanks for the info never knew dat :)